# How does SELECT 'TABLE_NAME' AS TEMP work?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I found this (working) statement in some code I maintain:

```
SELECT 'TABLE_NAME' AS TEMP
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

and while I am familiar with the `AS` use for table **columns**, e.g.

```
USE mydatabase;

SELECT day_of_order AS "Date", 
customer As "Client", 
product, 
quantity
FROM orders;
```

I couldn't find documentation for using the *entire table's name as a column*.

How does this work? and what would be the intended use of such statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just looks like they're selecting a literal string of the table name, and put it in a column called `TEMP`. It will only return one row because of the `WHERE ROWNUM = 1`.  They could have just as easily done:

```
SELECT 'TABLE_NAME' AS TEMP FROM DUAL
```

As for what you'd use it for... that's a good question. :)

Comment: Validate the existence of the table as well as the table having at least one record?

Comment: BTW, how is that "DUAL" statement equivalent to the one in my OP if it doesn't refer to the actual TABLE_NAME?

Comment: That they're selecting **from** `TABLE_NAME` really doesn't matter. What they are selecting is the actual string `'TABLE_NAME'`. It's a literal value, it's not coming from a column (or some other magic).

Comment: Actually, the table name *does* matter. That's how this statement checks that *that* particular table (in our case `TABLE_NAME`) is not empty.

Comment: Well that makes sense, then. In that case, you could have picked any literal (ex: `SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ROWNUM = 1`)